# MySQL: how to get list innodb file names in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Is there an SQL command to get the list of files currently mysql InnoDB engine?

NOTE: I have an mysql folder which a lot of files and I'm not sure which ones are the actually used.

Comment: currently mysql InnoDB engine what? that question misses a verb severely.

Answer (score 0):

There is, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-backup.html) for details. Basically, in the mysql data directory, there is a subdirectory per database, within it, there are files per table and so you can gather which are and aren't used. I just confirmed this on our [mysql](http://mysql.com) instance on Linux.